# Error inflating class fragment Duplicate ID, tag null, or parent id with another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

How can i solve this error?
**Error inflating class fragment Duplicate ID, tag null, or parent id with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment**.. I want to display a map in a dialog layout after sliding  my arrow button using SlideToActView.. when the slide isComplete() my pop up show up and display the map. When i slide the button for the first time , he work fine, with all locations in the map , but after dismissing the dialog and try to show the map again... app crash whth that error.

```
Duplicate id 0x7f0a00a2, tag null, or parent id 0x7f0a0004 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
```

her is my code

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal); 
 slideToActView = (SlideToActView) findViewById(R.id.example_gray_on_green);
slideToActView.setOnSlideCompleteListener(new SlideToActView.OnSlideCompleteListener() {
    @Override
public void onSlideComplete(SlideToActView slideToActView) {
    PopupMap();
    slideToActView.resetSlider();
}
});
private void PopupMap() {
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Principal.this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_popup);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
//dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = animationSource;
ImageView imgclose = dialog.findViewById(R.id.imgClose);
getLocationPermission();/* Ahi arranca el mapa*/

imgclose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.dismiss();
               }
});
dialog.show();
}
```

Her is where the map is calling

```
 private void getLocationPermission() {
    Log.d("", "getLocationPermission: getting location permissions");
    String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
            FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                COURSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
            //getDeviceLocation();
            initMap();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    permissions,
                    LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                permissions,
                LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
 private void initMap() {
    Log.d("", "initMap: initializing map");
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapPrincipal);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync((OnMapReadyCallback) Principal.this);
}
```

and here is my layout xml file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/Mycountain"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:elevation="3dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-1dp"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mapPrincipal"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="35dp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="596dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/mapPrincipal"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"

    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgClose"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"

        android:layout_marginBottom="-2dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close"
        tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your layout file

Comment: @MichaelStoddart i just did it , thank you man

Answer (score 0):

This because in procedure PopupMap you call getLocationPermission at this initmap is call again, 
Im recommended to remove getLocationPermission at popupmap and place getLocationPermission at oncreate
like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal); 
    getLocationPermission();/* Move at this place*/
 slideToActView = (SlideToActView) findViewById(R.id.example_gray_on_green);
slideToActView.setOnSlideCompleteListener(new SlideToActView.OnSlideCompleteListener() {
    @Override
public void onSlideComplete(SlideToActView slideToActView) {
    PopupMap();
    slideToActView.resetSlider();
}
});
private void PopupMap() {
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Principal.this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_popup);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
//dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = animationSource;
ImageView imgclose = dialog.findViewById(R.id.imgClose);

imgclose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.dismiss();
               }
});
dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: pumama i tried your answer but he didnt work when i place getLocationPermision  in the onCreate, error :Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference

Comment: sory im miss to place getLocationPermission(); at on create ex. at bottom of setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to make a `field` of `View` and use that `View` for your dialog and then you will have to check if that `View` is `null` or not. If `null` then you can inflate if not use same `View`. For example:

```
private View dialogView;
```

then inside your method `PopupMap` where you create dialog:

```
if(dialogView == null)
    dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_popup, null);
dialog.setContentView(dialogView);
```

Comment: thank you @Yupi, but now i show me a new error ::You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: @ApseSony can you first call `dialog.setContentView(null);` and then below `dialog.setContentView(dialogView);` check will that help?